# Android TextInputLayout endIcon not visible until I start typing

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I have set the endIconMode to 'clear_text'. This icon is visible only when the user starts typing even if there was already text in the field. Is there a way to force this icon to always be visible?

Comment: I believe you can call `textInputLayout.setEndIconVisible(true);` to force it to be shown at all times. Does it not work that way anymore?

Comment: Alternatively, I recommend you _peek_ at [the source code of the components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/dce4419744ba4e336e31a80521ab8a9ecb1136de/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield), as you can then see what these methods really do behind the scenes.